# LaTeX: Rotated header lines in table beginning in the same line

Tags: tables, rotating

i have  a table with rotated text. All these header lines should start near the second `\hline` (similar to "Abs.") like

```
hline
   C
  BC
  BCD
1 BCD
l BCD
o BCD Frequency
CABCD Abs   Rel
hline
```

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrr}
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=cb]{90}{Col1}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=cb]{90}{A}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=cb]{90}{BBBBB}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=cb]{90}{CCCCCC}} & \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=lc]{90}{DDDDD}} & & \\
& & & & & &\\
& & & & & &\\
& & & & & &\\
& & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Frequency} \\
& & & & & Abs. & Rel.\\
\hline
1&9&8&7&6&5&4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried different origin like `l`, `r`, `cB`, `cb`, `ct`, ... but it doesn't look like the way i would prefer. what do i wrong? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use all those `\multirow`s; here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
\hline
& & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{7}{*}{Frequency}} 
\\
\rotatebox{90}{Col1} & \rotatebox{90}{A} & \rotatebox{90}{BBBBB} 
  & \rotatebox{90}{CCCCCC} & \rotatebox{90}{DDDDD} & Abs. & Rel. \\
\hline
1&9&8&7&6&5&4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, to make your tables look professional, you might be interested in the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package (this implies that your tables won't use vertical rules):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
\toprule
& & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{7}{*}{Frequency}} 
\\
\rotatebox{90}{Col1} & \rotatebox{90}{A} & \rotatebox{90}{BBBBB} 
  & \rotatebox{90}{CCCCCC} & \rotatebox{90}{DDDDD} & Abs. & Rel. \\
\midrule
1&9&8&7&6&5&4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tnx a lot mr. gonzalo medina for your helping hand :)!

Comment: @MyUser you're welcome! Don't forget that you can up-vote good answers and accept the one you consider best solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).